# qTranslate Wordpress - set language that redirects to another URL

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate, qtranslate-x

I am using the Wordpress plugin - qTranslate X and I have 3 languages on my site. I have content for 2 of the languages already set on my site, but I want to redirect the 3rd language to another domain.

For example, I have example.com for the English content, and I want users to get redirected to example.it for the Italian content (the current link is example.com/it). I am using the plugins menu display option (not widget in sidebar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at [this page](http://webmaestro.fr/a-different-domain-for-each-language-with-qtranslate/). Hopefully it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: Post has been removed from link